# JPQL Console in Intellij without persistence.xml

Tags: hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, jpql

I am looking for a tool to test my JPQL queries. I am aware the Intellij has built in JPQL console but I don't seem to be able to get it working. I am using Spring Boot 1.2.5 with Spring Data JPA (Hibernate is the JPA implementation). It seems to be looking for persistence.xml or hibernate.cfg.xml, neither exists in my project.

[image]

I have the facets and modules added as well. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work for me by adding JPA to my module.

From the project settings (shortcut F4). Right click the module -> Add JPA . I then did not specify an XML or a provider.

When I opened the persistence window, it had picked up my entityManagers, and I could use the console.